# In shell script, how to change current directory safely with variable?

Tags: shell, command-line, cd

The following shell script changes current the directory to the desktop.

```
v=~/Desktop/
cd $v
pwd # desktop
```

The following script changes the current directory to home directory instead of generating error.

```
cd $undefined_variable
pwd # home directory
echo $? # 0
```

I'm afraid that the script will remove important files if I misspelled a variable for new current directory.

Generally, how do you safely change current directory with variable in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `set -u` to make `bash` exit with an error each time you expand an undefined variable.

Comment: other answers are also great but `set -u` is the easiest solution. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`cd ${variable:?}`

if $variable is not defined or empty then bash will throw an error and exit. It's like the `set -u` option but not global through the file.

Comment: You can also supply an error message: `${variable:?Variable is unset or empty}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `test -d` condition (checks whether the specified variable is a directory), i.e.

```
if [[ -d $undefined_variable ]]
then
  cd $undefined_variable
  echo "This will not be printed if $undefined_variable is not defined"
fi
```

See also [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) for further test options...

Answer (score 1):

The Bourne Shells have a **construct to substitute a value for undefined variables**, `${varname-subtitution}`. You can use this to have a safe fallback directory in case the variable is undefined:

```
 cd "${undefined-/tmp/backupdir}"
```

If there is a variable named `undefined`, its value is substituted, otherwise `/tmp/backupdir` is substituted.

Note that I also put the variable expansion in double quotes. This is used to prevent *word splitting* on strings containing spaces (very common for Windows directories). This way it works even for directories with spaces.

For the gory details on all the shell substitution constructs (there are seven more for POSIX shells), read your shell manual's **Parameter Substitution** section.

Comment: thanks for useful information! I didn't know there was a cool feature like Parameter Substitution. I should learn shell script more.

Answer (score 1):

You have to *write* a wrapper (this work in bash):

```
cd() {
    if [ $# -ne 1 ] ;then
        echo "cd need exactly 1 argument" >&2
        return 2
      fi
    builtin cd "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's shell
if you type `cd` without parameter it will jump to home dir.
You can can check the variable of null or empty before you `cd` command.

check like (cd only be called if targetDir is not empty):

```
test -z "$targetDir" || cd $targetDir
```

check like (cd only be called if targetDir really exist):

```
test -d "$targetDir" && cd $targetDir
```

**Note:** Thanks for -1, should read the last  sentence too. So I added the real answer.